# PHP string cut in pieces

Tags: php, function, output

i have a login form, where the user must type in his e-mail address.
Now i want to cut off the `@` and the e-mail domain and save this as username.

For example:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
//$email = muster.hans@gmail.com
```

now the username should be:

```
muser.hans
```

Comment: With [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strstr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
echo strstr( $_POST['email'],'@',true);
```